# Problema con consulta like

Tags: php, laravel, base-de-datos, eloquent

Buenos días, tengo esta consulta que es como un buscador, solo para productos donde la marca sea "forte".. en el parametro $palabra, puede traer unicamente una descripción del producto o código.

Cuando envio una descripción del producto me funciona el buscador, pero cuando envio un código me trae como resultado codigos de otras marcas, pero solo necesito de la marca forte.

```
public static function busqueda($palabra){

$producto = self::join('ped_unidades_medida','vcomp_productos_web1.unidad','=','ped_unidades_medida.unidad_uid')
    ->where('vcomp_productos_web1.marca','forte')
    ->where('vcomp_productos_web1.descripcion','like','%'.$palabra.'%')
    ->orwhere('vcomp_productos_web1.codigo','like','%'.$palabra.'%')
    ->select(['vcomp_productos_web1.*','ped_unidades_medida.unidad_descripcion'])
    ->where('vcomp_productos_web1.venta_web','SI')
    ->paginate(9);

    return $producto;
```

}

Un resultado cuando busco por descripción

[image: Busqueda por descripción]

Cuando ingreso un código de un producto que no es forte me trae este resultado, que es erroneo.. deberia buscar solo por productos donde la marca sea forte.

[image: Busqueda por código]

Dejo por acá la consulta SQL. Supongamos que $palabra es 18

```
SELECT * FROM vcomp_productos_web1 
JOIN ped_unidades_medida ON vcomp_productos_web1.unidad = ped_unidades_medida.unidad_uid
WHERE vcomp_productos_web1.marca = 'FORTE'
AND vcomp_productos_web1.venta_web = 'SI'
AND vcomp_productos_web1.descripcion LIKE '%$palabra%'
OR vcomp_productos_web1.codigo LIKE '%$palabra%'
```

Comment: Podrás imprimir la consulta SQL que genera el ORM?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Debes usar una clausula en el where de la siguiente manera:

```
->where(function ($query) use ($palabra) {
     $query->where('vcomp_productos_web1.descripcion','like','%'.$palabra.'%')
           ->orWhere('vcomp_productos_web1.codigo','like','%'.$palabra.'%');
    })
```

Quedando el código de la siguiente manera:

```
public static function busqueda($palabra){

$producto = 
self::join('ped_unidades_medida','vcomp_productos_web1.unidad','=','ped_unidades_medida.unidad_uid')
        ->where('vcomp_productos_web1.marca','forte')
        ->where(function ($query) use ($palabra) {
                    $query->where('vcomp_productos_web1.descripcion','like','%'.$palabra.'%')
                          ->orWhere('vcomp_productos_web1.codigo','like','%'.$palabra.'%');
    })
    ->select(['vcomp_productos_web1.*','ped_unidades_medida.unidad_descripcion'])
    ->where('vcomp_productos_web1.venta_web','SI')
    ->paginate(9);

    return $producto;
```

Puedes revisar la documentación [aquí](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#parameter-grouping)

Comment: Me salio este error, ErrorException in vcomp_productos_web1.php line 195:
Undefined variable: palabra

Comment: ya actualice la respuesta, faltaba incluir el uso de la variable dentro de la autofuncion del where.

Comment: Coméntame si te funcionó @RubxnMC y si fue así no olvides calificar la respuesta como la solución a tu problema.

Comment: Muchas gracias bro!

Answer (score 3):

El problema principal es que en la consulta está mal armada. Debés tener en cuenta que primero resuelve los `AND` y después los `OR`, por ende tu query:

```
SELECT * FROM vcomp_productos_web1 
JOIN ped_unidades_medida ON vcomp_productos_web1.unidad = ped_unidades_medida.unidad_uid
# resuelve primero esto, si es false entonces consulta por el 'codigo'
# evitando toda sub consulta anterior
WHERE (
  vcomp_productos_web1.marca = 'FORTE'
  AND vcomp_productos_web1.venta_web = 'SI'
  AND vcomp_productos_web1.descripcion LIKE '%$palabra%'
)
OR vcomp_productos_web1.codigo LIKE '%$palabra%'
```

Lo que deberías hacer es agregarle un grupo al `where` del `OR`:

```
SELECT * FROM vcomp_productos_web1 
JOIN ped_unidades_medida ON vcomp_productos_web1.unidad = ped_unidades_medida.unidad_uid
# en este caso hace las comprobaciones de si la marca es 'FORTE'
# y si venta_web es 'SI' para luego buscar por la palabra en
# descripcion o codigo
WHERE
  vcomp_productos_web1.marca = 'FORTE'
  AND vcomp_productos_web1.venta_web = 'SI'
  AND (
    vcomp_productos_web1.descripcion LIKE '%$palabra%'
    OR vcomp_productos_web1.codigo LIKE '%$palabra%'
  )
```

**En tu código:**

```
public static function busqueda($palabra){

$producto = self::join('ped_unidades_medida','vcomp_productos_web1.unidad','=','ped_unidades_medida.unidad_uid')
    ->where('vcomp_productos_web1.marca','forte')
    ->where(function($query) {
      $query->where('vcomp_productos_web1.descripcion','like','%'.$palabra.'%')
      $query->orwhere('vcomp_productos_web1.codigo','like','%'.$palabra.'%')
    })
    ->select(['vcomp_productos_web1.*','ped_unidades_medida.unidad_descripcion'])
    ->where('vcomp_productos_web1.venta_web','SI')
    ->paginate(9);

return $producto;
```